# How to make ajax POST Call in Visual studio Rest API

Tags: c#, ajax, post, internal-server-error

It has been 2 days I am stuck at a stupid error. I cant make an ajax post call. Can any one help me solving what I am doing wrong. It will be great. I am always getting 500 internal server error. I know what error means, but how to get rid of it. Below is my ajax function which always returns 'fail'

```js
 function Add() {
        var Tname = document.getElementById("TaskName").value.trim();
        var Sdate = document.getElementById("StartDate").value.trim();
        var Edate = document.getElementById("EndDate").value.trim();
        var sms = document.getElementById("chkSMS").checked;
        var email = document.getElementById("chkEmail").checked;
        var assigned = document.getElementById("test").value.trim();

        if (Tname == "")
        {
            alert("Please enter Your Task Name");
            return;
        }
        if (Sdate >= Edate)
        {
            alert("Please Correct the Start And End date");
            return;
        }
        
            var user = $("#test").select2("val");
            console.log(user);

            var model = {
                id:$("#secid").val(),
                projectId: $("#ProjectDropdown").val(),
                task_name: $("#TaskName").val(),
                description: $("#Desc").val(),
                start_date: $("#StartDate").val(),
                end_date: $("#EndDate").val(),
                sms: document.getElementById("chkSMS").checked,
                email: document.getElementById("chkEmail").checked,
                status:"1",
                tempUsers: user
            };
            console.log(model);
            $.ajax
                (
                    {
              
                url: '/api/TaskApi/',
                type: 'POST',
                data: model,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert('Task Added');
                   // location.reload(); // this is not a good practice
                },
                error: function () { alert('Task not Added'); }
            });
        
    }
```

```html
   [Route("/api/TaskApi/"), HttpPost]
        public String CreateTask(tempTask tempTask )
        {

            Task task = new Task();
            task.enable = true;
            task.created_on = DateTime.Now;
            task.task_name = tempTask.task_name;
            task.description = tempTask.description;
            task.start_date = tempTask.start_date;
            task.end_date = tempTask.end_date;
            task.status = tempTask.status;
            task.sms = tempTask.sms;
            task.email = tempTask.email;
            db.task.Add(task);
            Tagging tag = new Tagging();
            tag.tasks = task;
            tag.project = db.project.Find(tempTask.projectId);
            List<Users> usr = new List<Users>();
            for (int i = 0; i < tempTask.tempUsers.Count; i++)
            {

                var user = db.user.Find(tempTask.tempUsers[i]);
                usr.Add(user);
            }
            tag.users = usr;
            db.tagging.Add(tag);
            if (db.SaveChanges() > 0)
            {
                return "task success!!";

            }
            else
            {
                return "Some Error";
            }

           
        }
```

**EDIT**:
I just need to hit the first line of Code in my c# method of CreateTask.  I cant hit it.  Rest of the code and view model is fine. I have checked.

**EDIT:**
json.strigify(model) //output in console
{"id":"0","projectId":"6007","task_name":"fgfg","description":"fgf","start_date":"2017-05-05","end_date":"2017-05-11","sms":false,"email":true,"status":"1","tempUsers":["1003"]}

```js
   public class tempTask
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int projectId { get; set; }
        public string task_name { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public DateTime start_date { get; set; }
        public DateTime end_date { get; set; }
        public bool sms { get; set; }
        public bool email { get; set; }
        public int status { get; set; }
        public List<int> tempUsers { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Could you try passing just an integer and check whether its working.. then proceed further..

Comment: Can you post your modal..

Comment: I can post every thing... Tell me which modal?  a bit detailed

Comment: added my temptask modal @asif raza

Comment: Hope your API Controller is public

Comment: public class TaskApiController : ApiController

Comment: can u change your route url to `/api/TaskApi/Create/` and try

Comment: Still are you facing problem ??

Comment: `I am always getting 500 internal server error.` what this error says ? What is in the response of this hit?

Comment: @Manoz make sure url , paratmer must be same as

Answer (score 1):

[image]
Problem thai i find in your code
1) URL of you web api
2) Sending data to server , make as it , as controller want
Ajax Code

```
         $('#postdata').click(function() {
           // alert('alert btn click');

            // Dear Nim , i'm just using dafault value , its working from my side

            var userArray = [];
            var user = 1 ; //get the value of user , push into array , then send to it.
            userArray.push(user);

            //you can loop it through 
           // for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
           //     userArray.push(i)
          //  }

            var model = {
                id: 0,  //should be integer , parse to parseInt(value)
                projectId: 1, //should be integer , parse to parseInt(value)
                task_name:"sdfsadfsadf",
                description: "description",
                start_date: '13-12-2007',
                end_date: '13-12-2007',
                sms: true,
                email: true,
                status: 1, //should be integer , parse to parseInt(value)
                tempUsers: userArray // array of integer
            };

            console.log('modal')
            console.log(model)
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'http://localhost:3153/api/TaskApi',
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    dataType: 'text',
                    async: false,
                    traditional: true,
                    data: JSON.stringify(model),
                    success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                             //alert here data
                        if (xhr.statusText == 'Created' && xhr.status == 201) {
                         //do stuff here
                        }
                        else {
                          //do stuff here
                        }

                    },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert('error')

                    }
                });


        })
    })
```

Controller

```
    [Route("api/TaskApi")]
    [HttpPost]
    public String TaskApi(tempTask tempTask)
    {
        return "Some Message";
    }

    public class tempTask
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int projectId { get; set; }
        public string task_name { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public DateTime start_date { get; set; }
        public DateTime end_date { get; set; }
        public bool sms { get; set; }
        public bool email { get; set; }
        public int status { get; set; }
        public List<int> tempUsers { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: traditional: true, add it

Comment: Code Update , Please look

Answer (score 0):

Just try,

```
  $.ajax
    ({
    url: '/api/TaskApi/',
    type: 'POST',
    data: Json.stringyfy(model),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        alert('Task Added');
        // location.reload(); // this is not a good practice
    },
    error: function() { alert('Task not Added'); }
});
```

Comment: I tried the same json.stringyfy first. but same issue.

Comment: @nimraasad did you try with the url  '/api/TaskApi'

Comment: yup! Nothing happened

Comment: do you have teamviewer?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you register the routeAttribute in RouteConfig under AppStart folder.

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

set these before, setup all routes configuration.

Comment: This is a continued project and before this ajax call i have made multiple of post put and get calls with empty and fileld models as parameters all are working...  Hence proved that I have configured routes in my AppStart ;) @ankit

Comment: @nimraasad, can you please also add the JSON.stringyfy(model) output in question, I think error occur while model binding process.

Comment: how to get the strigify output to post here ? @ ankit can u guide?

Comment: added that strigify output in my question as well

Comment: it looks all fine, did you request to create a controller mean to send a request and add a break point on controller constructor. see if request reaches the constructor break point means your controller instance created and your issue lies in a model binding side.